# How do I run vba scripts embedded in a spreadsheet in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, web-services, aspose-cells

We have a .Net/C# based web service.
Within the service, we use a spreadsheet as a calculationr engine.
We're using Apose.Cells for .Net to populate the spreadsheet cells.

Calculations are performed through VB script embedded in the spreadsheet.
To be able to generate results, I need to be able to run/trigger the VB script.

Aspose does not seem to support this functionality. 
It can poke/retrieve data and force recalc of any formulae that exist in the spreadsheet, but not run macros/VB script.

Once I've uploaded the desired data into the spreadsheet, how do I run the macros through .Net?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: Why to force to run VBA scripts, if you can complete the job within .net code?

Comment: Maciej:  Good point, but not an option. We HAVE to use the spreadsheet provided for us. This is not a point for debate.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells cannot run macros. Besides, we are afraid, there is no server-side solution for your problem too. However on client-side (local machine) you can execute macros using Microsoft Office APIs. Please use the namespace

i.e

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Here is an example how to make use of it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/2e33b8e5-c9fd-42a1-8d67-3d61d2cedc1c/how-to-call-excel-macros-programmatically-in-c?forum=exceldev

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: shakeel: My application is an MS Web Service. Based on the reading I've seen so far, people advise against using Microsoft.Office.Interop (com objects) in Web Services. What are your recommendations?

Comment: You are right. This is not a server-side solution and it needs MS-Office installed and it runs on local machine, so it is not a good solution but I am afraid, it is the only solution. Please create and execute a little example and it will tell you about all the limitations of it. Once, you had some idea about it, then please post your questions on stack over flow website and get the help of the people. May be you could find out some solution feasible for your requirements. Best wishes.